# How to find which Schema Registry pod/node is currently the master

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have deployed 3 schema registry pods on a k8s cluster. 
I am trying to find which schema registry pod is currently acting as a master.

I have figured it out one way to find master through schema registry logs. Here I have to check all pods logs manually.

Is there any command or configuration file in schema-registry to get the current master?

Comment: "check all pods logs manually" - Well, if you setup something like Filebeat/Fluentd into Elasticsearch, you wouldn't need to do that. Anyways, the answer here depends if using Zookeeper or Kafka based election because the master id will be written into Zookeeper

Answer (score 1):

Get the master SR from ZK:

```
/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] get /schema_registry/schema_registry_master
{"host":"host name of current master schema registry","port":8081,"master_eligibility":true,"scheme":"http","version":1}
cZxid = ...
ctime = ...
mZxid = ...
mtime = ...
pZxid = ...
cversion = ...
dataVersion = ...
aclVersion = ...
ephemeralOwner = ...
dataLength = ...
numChildren = ...
```